# Can I call a dict of python objects from with a method of another class?

Tags: python

I've created a class called Emp has attributes like employee number, department number, employee type etc.  I've used this class to populate a dictionary called emp_dict.

I've done a similar thing for Dept with details of the department, now I want to create a method in the department class to measure the number contractors in this class but do do this I reference the emp_dict.

```
class Dept():
    def __init__(self,deptno, deptname):
        self.deptno = deptno
    def contractor_count(self,qtr,emp_dict): 
        contractor_count = 0
        if qtr in ['FY14Q1A','FY14Q2A','FY14Q3A','FY14Q4A',\
               'FY15Q1A','FY15Q2A','FY15Q3A','FY15Q4A',\
               'FY16Q1A','FY16Q2A','FY16Q3A','FY16Q4A',\
               'FY17Q1A','FY17Q2A','FY17Q3A','FY17Q4A']:
            for worker in self.allo[qtr].keys():
                if emp_dict[worker].emptype != "R" :
                    contractor_count_= 1
        return contractor_count
```

When I tried using the count_contractor method it returns the initial value: 0 
Should I be using another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contractor_count` variable is never touched again.  You have:

```
contractor_count_= 1
```

Did you mean this?

```
contractor_count += 1
```

I would also recommend using a variable name that is different from the method name, to avoid possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a spelling error, and hit `_` instead of `+`:

your code should be:

```
class Dept():
def __init__(self,deptno, deptname):
    self.deptno = deptno
def contractor_count(self,qtr,emp_dict): 
    contractor_count = 0
    if qtr in ['FY14Q1A','FY14Q2A','FY14Q3A','FY14Q4A',\
           'FY15Q1A','FY15Q2A','FY15Q3A','FY15Q4A',\
           'FY16Q1A','FY16Q2A','FY16Q3A','FY16Q4A',\
           'FY17Q1A','FY17Q2A','FY17Q3A','FY17Q4A']:
        for worker in self.allo[qtr].keys():
            if emp_dict[worker].emptype != "R" :
                contractor_count+= 1
    return contractor_count
```

The correction for the line: `contractor_count+= 1`